# Exim + Dovecot sending or receiving an email occurs the error: Unknown user

Tags: centos, smtp, dovecot, exim, vestacp

I'm running a mail server with CentOS 7 + Exim 4.92 + Dovecot 2.2.36 and RoundCubeMail as web interface, and have the following problem: when I send to or receive from emails which is not admin@ or info@ or dev@ etc. I have the following error:

```
2020-04-05 05:37:52 H=mail.mydomain.com (IP) [IP] sender verify fail for <bender@mydomain.com>: Unknown user
2020-04-05 05:37:52 H=mail.mydomain.com (IP) [IP] F=<bender@mydomain.com> A=dovecot_login:bender@mydomain.com rejected RCPT <admin@mydomain.com>: Sender verify failed
```

Here I tried to send an email from bender@mydomain.com to admin@mydomain.com. But if I send an email from admin to info, or from dev to info everything goes well: emails are sent and received, no errors occur.

If I send an email to bender@mydomain.ru then I receive returned message:

> Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
>
> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> bender@mydomain.com
>       Unknown user Reporting-MTA: dns; mail.mydomain.com
>
> Action: failed
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;bender@mydomain.com
>
> Status: 5.0.0

All mailboxes was created via VESTA CP and really exist, **passwd** file locates in /home/user/conf/mail/mydomain.com/ and contains entries like:

```
bender:{MD5}$1$XXX:user:mail::/home/user:0
```

**Mail server host**: mail.mydomain.com

**MX entry**: mail.mydomain.com

There is authentication via dovecot in the exim config file:

```
dovecot_login:
  driver = dovecot
  public_name = LOGIN
  server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  server_set_id = $auth1

dovecot_plain:
  driver = dovecot
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  server_set_id = $auth1
```

Dovecot's **10-auth.conf** file contains following entries:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_verbose = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-passwdfile.conf.ext
```

Dovecot's **auth-passwdfile.conf.ext**:

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=MD5-CRYPT username_format=%n /etc/exim/domains/%d/passwd
}

userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%n /etc/exim/domains/%d/passwd
}
```

**/etc/exim/domains/mydomain.com** - symlink exactly to **/home/user/conf/mail/mydomain.com/**

I can successfully login to RoundCube web interface with all these mail accounts.

I spent 3 days trying to find the answer in the Internet and tried to change exim/dovecot config files, but nothing helped. And I'm stuck. I guess that emails like admin/info/dev are some trusted standards, or exist somewhere in the previous passwd file/config file, but I didn't find any on my server, and anyway if I change username or password hash in /home/user/conf/mail/mydomain.com/passwd I even can't login to RoundCubeMail and send an email. I'm new to mail servers so I don't even have an idea where to dig, I tried everything I could with my knowledge.

P.S. exim and dovecot comes with VESTA CP, but I removed and installed them manually because of mysql dependencies of upgrading to latest version.

Comment: **Important**: you should change your password, since you posted it on this site. Concerning your problem: **exim4** does not know any user `bender`, check the [routers section](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_runtime_configuration_file.html#SECTconffilfor) of your config file and add the router configuration for local domains to your question.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz in config file I have this entry: 
localuser:
  driver = accept
  check_local_user
# local_part_suffix = +* : -*
# local_part_suffix_optional
  transport = local_delivery
  cannot_route_message = Unknown user

What else should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dovecot configuration is configured to use a **virtual users** database, i.e. your e-mail users are not system users of your server. On the other hand **Exim** is only configured to deliver mail to local system users.

You need to configure it to use the Dovecot user database (cf. [Dovecot documentation](https://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Exim)). Therefore:

- Comment out your `localuser` router,
- Add a router to check for Dovecot users just after the `localuser` router:

  ```
  dovecot_local_users:
      driver = accept
      domains = +local_domains
      # Requires fixing permission, so that Exim can read it
      local_parts = lsearch;/etc/exim/domains/${domain}/passwd
      transport = dovecot_delivery
  ```
- Add a `transport` anywhere in the transport section (as described in the aforementioned link):

  ```
  dovecot_delivery:
      driver = pipe
      # The path to the dovecot-lda binary may differ on your system
      command = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $local_part@$domain -f $sender_address
      message_prefix =
      message_suffix =
      log_output
      delivery_date_add
      envelope_to_add
      return_path_add
      # Set the appropriate user and group, which your mailboxes use.
      #user =
      #group = mail
      #mode = 0660
      temp_errors = 64 : 69 : 70: 71 : 72 : 73 : 74 : 75 : 78
  ```
- Test the routing configuration with:

  ```
  /usr/sbin/exim4 -bt address_to_test
  ```

**Edit**: The `lsearch;/etc/exim/domains/${domain}/passwd` requires you to give **Exim4** access to the **dovecot**'s `passwd` files. That might be a security risk, since this file contains real passwords. So you can:

- Comment out the `local_parts` condition. No `passwd` file access will be required, **but** your server will accept **any** username during the `SMTP` session and generate a bounce message for the non-existent usernames afterwards. Since most `Return-Path` addresses in spam messages are spoofed, this will deliver the message to the wrong address.
- Generate and maintain a second file, which will contain just the usernames of the virtual users:

  ```
  user1:
  user2:
  user3:
  ```

  and give it as argument to `lsearch`.

By the way, you should consider changing your password scheme in Dovecot (cf. [Dovecot documentation](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/password_schemes/#what-scheme-to-use)) into something more modern, line **SHA512-CRYPT** used in the `/etc/shadow` files of modern distributions.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it works! Couldn't find these blocks from googling, it seems better to learn documentation itself. There are another problems now with permissions, but it should be already another topic I think. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding the permission problem with the access to `/etc/exim/domains/${domain}/passwd` I added some details to the answer.

Comment: Oh, this is exaclty I was reading about now, very useful information, thank you again! Could you give me advice please: I'm going to choose option 2 (generate file with only usernames), so where is better to store this file and what permission rights should it have? Btw, my dovecot-lda owned by `root` and has group `mail`, is it correct/safe? Exim and Dovecot are have group `mail` as well.

Comment: The user list does not contain sensitive data, so it can be `root:root` with a `0644` mode (in a directory writable only by root with all its ancestors, cf. [path_resolution](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)). The `passwd` file can be `root:dovecot` (the group containing just `dovecot`) with a `0640` mode, since you will probably update the passwords yourself. The e-mails can be stored as `dovecot:mail` with a `0660` mode.